# Haskell couldn't match weird expected type

Tags: list, haskell, types

I have a List `[(String, [(String, Float)]` and want to calculate the average of the floats, so that I get as result `[(String, Float)]`. You'll understand reading the code.

```
type StudentName = String
type CourseName  = String
type ExamScore   = (CourseName, Float)
type StudentData = [(StudentName, [ExamScore])]

--Delete duplicated entries
filterDuplicates :: StudentData -> StudentData
filterDuplicates [] = []
filterDuplicates sd = [(head sd)] ++ filterDuplicates(filter (\ x -> x /= (head sd)) (tail sd))

--Delete entries whose score is not in scope or whose are not listed the list of course names
filterValidEntries :: [ExamScore] -> [CourseName] -> [ExamScore]
filterValidEntries es cn = filter (\ x -> ((fst x) `elem` cn) && ((snd x) >= 1.0 && (snd x) <= 5.0)) es

--Calulate the average of the cleared data
calculateAverages :: StudentData -> [CourseName] -> [(StudentName, Float)]
calculateAverages sd cn = map createTupel (filterDuplicates sd)
    where createTupel x = ((fst x), ((foldr (+) 0 (snd(filterValidEntries(snd x) cn))) / fromIntegral(length (filterValidEntries(snd x) cn))))
```

Trying to compile this, I am getting the following error:

```
    * Couldn't match expected type `(a0, t0 b)'
                  with actual type `[ExamScore]'
    * In the first argument of `snd', namely
        `(filterValidEntries (snd x) cn)'
      In the third argument of `foldr', namely
        `(snd (filterValidEntries (snd x) cn))'
      In the first argument of `(/)', namely
        `(foldr (+) 0 (snd (filterValidEntries (snd x) cn)))'
    * Relevant bindings include
        createTupel :: (a, [ExamScore]) -> (a, b)
          (bound at C:\\Users\Lennart\sciebo\Semster 1\Info\Übungen\Übung 06\WI0
4_B06_A04_G01.hs:72:15)
   |
72 |         where createTupel x = ((fst x), ((foldr (+) 0 (snd(filterValidEntri
es(snd x) cn))) / fromIntegral(length (filterValidEntries(snd x) cn))))
   |                                                            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

I hope you can help me, thank you.

Comment: Hint: a 2-tuple is not the same as a *list* of 2-tuples.

Comment: Where is the data coming from in the first place that you need to remove duplicates? Are you building that list? You might want to use `Data.Map` to make it easier to update without adding duplicates to the collection in the first place.

Comment: I dont get it. filterValidEntries does require a list of ExamScores and the second argurment is such a list... Where is the problem? @Willem

It is my homework chepner. How do you mean I can use map?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A minor, but important, comment on style.  Haskell function application is *never* written `f(x+y)` without space between the `f` and `(`.  It's always written `f (x+y)`.

Anyway, here's how to figure out this error message.  The important bits are that GHC expected a type of the form `(a, t b)` -- the `a`, `t`, and `b` are less important than the fact that it expected a tuple (i.e., pair) type, but it was given an `[ExamScore]`, which is clearly a list and not the tuple it expected.

Where did this happen?  Well, as the error message says, the problem occurred in trying to pass the first argument to `snd` -- namely `(filterValidEntries (snd x) cn)`.

Note that `snd`, since it grabs the second element of a tuple, obviously **expected** a tuple.  Yet, the argument `filterValidEntries (snd x) cn` does not return a tuple, it **actually** returns a list `[ExamScore]`.

That's your problem.  Did you really intend to pass the argument `filterValidEntries (snd x) cn`, which returns a list, to the function `snd`, which expects a tuple?  No, you did not.  What *were* you trying to do?  Maybe map `snd` to each element of the list?

Comment: Ahhh okay I got it. `(map (snd) (filterValidEntries (snd x) cn))` did it. Thank you for the hint.